# 2 Navigation Properties of same type EF Core 1.1

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have 2 tables Match and Team . Match table should hold the HomeTeam and AwayTeam but these teams are not permanent , a new team is created every time a match is created by a host . So basically there should be a one-to-one relationship of

HomeTeam -> Match 
       and
 AwayTeam -> Match

I've created the models like this .

```
 public class Team
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public Match Match { get; set; }
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
 public class Match
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public Sport Sport { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public int Difficulty { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
    public int GuestTeamId { get; set; }
    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public virtual Team GuestTeam { get; set; }

}

 modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
            .HasOne(m => m.HomeTeam)
            .WithOne(m => m.Match)
            .HasForeignKey<Match>(p => p.HomeTeamId)
            .IsRequired();


        modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
            .HasOne(m => m.GuestTeam)
            .WithOne(m => m.Match)
            .HasForeignKey<Match>(p => p.GuestTeamId)
            .IsRequired();
```

But when adding migrations it shows me this error :

```
Cannot create a relationship between 'Team.Match' and 'Match.GuestTeam', because there already is a relationship between 'Team.Match' and 'Match.HomeTeam'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Core: Multiple Relationships between Users and Organizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112405/entity-framework-core-multiple-relationships-between-users-and-organizations)