# Entity Framework Core: Multiple Relationships between Users and Organizations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have 2 model classes for Users and Organizations.

```cs
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public int? OrganizationID { get; set; }

    public virtual OrgList org { get; set; }
}

public class OrgList
{
    public OrgList()
    {
        employees = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String ownerId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> employees { get; set; }
    public virtual User ownerUser { get; set; }
}
```

User can be owner of some organization and also he is employee of the same organization (But other employees can't be owners of the organization).

First i've created a relationship for employees and it works OK

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OrgList>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasMany(e => e.employees)
        .WithOne(e => e.org)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.OrganizationID)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
}
```

but when i try to add another relationship for owner

```
entity.HasOne(e => e.ownerUser)
    .WithOne(e => e.org)
    .HasForeignKey<OrgList>(e => e.ownerId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

i have an error on migration:

> Cannot create a relationship between 'User.org' and
>   'OrgList.ownerUser', because there already is a relationship between
>   'OrgList.employees' and 'User.org'. Navigation properties can only
>   participate in a single relationship.

How can i fix it? I've found an answers for EF6 (not EF Core) with `HasOptional()` and `WithOptionalPrincipal()` methods that not exist in EF Core.

Can i do it without creating additional table for employees or without creating additional `virtual OrgList` on User class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to create the owner relationship with the same property on the user that you are using for the employee relationship.  Entity framework wouldn't know which relationship to assign the property. If you created another property on the user like

```
public int? OwnedOrganizationID { get; set; }
public virtual OrgList OwnedOrg { get; set; }
```

and change the statement to

```
entity.HasOne(e => e.ownerUser)
.WithOne(e => e.OwnedOrg)
.HasForeignKey<OrgList>(e => e.ownerId)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

I imagine it should work.

Comment: I know about this. But in my example there's two only possible situations by design: 1) User is an employee and an owner of the same org 2) User is an employee of some org, but not an owner of any. If User owns an org then property `OwnedOrganizationId` links to same org as `OrganizationId`. So there's can be only one relationship as i guess. But anyway, it's a EF design (or my mind) problem, so i'll accept your answer for other generalized situations.

Comment: You would use navigation-less relationship like `entity.HasOne(e.ownerUser).WithOne().HasForeignKey<OrgList>(e => e.ownerId);` That way Org knows who is owner with navigation. And to check if user is owner or not, check `user.OrgList.ownerUser == user`